# I have a Python issue, trying to use polymorphism with my classes, how can I properly implement this? Does the loop need it's own class?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, types, polymorphism

When I run the below:

```
menu = 1
while menu == 1:
    for Stockitem in (Navsys, Wheelrims, Seatcovers, Airfresh):
        #In the next two lines we print the subclass 
        print ("Printing item stock information:\n ")
        print (Stockitem)
        #Then it calls the increase and decrease functions from Stockitem, the parent class, to apply to the subclass iteration in the tuple.
        Stockitem.increaseStock()
        Stockitem.sellStock()
    #Here we have our simple exit function
    menu = int(input("press enter 1 to reloop or anything else to exit: "))
    if menu != 1: 
        print ("Goodbye!")
```

I receive the error that increaseStock() requires the argument 'Self'. I instantiate an object as below:

```
Navsys = Airfresh('','','AF01','1','1.50','','')
menu = 1
while menu == 1:
    for Stockitem in (Navsys, Wheelrims, Seatcovers, Airfresh):
        #In the next two lines we print the subclass 
        print ("Printing item stock information:\n ")
        print (Stockitem)
        #Then it calls the increase and decrease functions from Stockitem, the parent class, to apply to the subclass iteration in the tuple.
        Stockitem.increaseStock()
        Stockitem.sellStock()
    #Here we have our simple exit function
    menu = int(input("press enter 1 to reloop or anything else to exit: "))
    if menu != 1: 
        print ("Goodbye!")
```

This gives me a new error:

```
return str(round(self.__pricewithVAT, 2))
```

TypeError: type str doesn't define **round** method

That is telling me there's an issue with my get method that returns price with VAT.. This is not an issue until I call it within the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: can you check the type of self.__pricewithVAT? type(self.__pricewithVAT)

Comment: Sorry - they are floats but they are converted to a string before being printed to control decimals.

Comment: did you try print out type(self.__pricewithVAT) in your getter? do you get type float everytime?

Comment: It actually returns STR.. what can I do to fix this?

Comment: I can change the Type to float using my setter. Then move on to the loop, however, then I get a new issue. The terminal tells me that the object Navsys is not iterable. Navsys being the name of one of my classes that inherits from the Stockitem parent class

Comment: is it a numerical string? or you have a-z in it?

Comment: Fully numerical string. It did not like being rounded so I removed that which is a pity as it's supposed to represent value. I can deal with that later though. I

Comment: samething, you need to figure out what type is Navsys, then you can figure out why it is not iterating. I recommend using "import pdb; pdb.set_trace" to help you debug this.

Comment: Navsys is the name of my class.. What I need to know is how to make my custom Classes iterable I think?